# convert key value of hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: c++, c, hex

I want to convert the key stroke representation to its decimal from.
eg :- the input string is

^@^D^@^A49

This should be converted to 0004000149
ie ^@ - 00
   ^D  -04
   ^A  -01
I found the correct values from the below link

http://techurls.tripod.com/dha.htm

Edit:-

The main problem is to map the values ie ^@ - 00    ^D  -04   ^A  -01

Is there any standard lib function or This is needed to be done using switch case?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. And that is not hexadecimal input; you have control character notation in there. Hexadecimals are 0-9 and A-F

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a magical code generator

Comment: @anurag I'm afraid your edit doesn't help much. Check what [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) can do for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have misunderstood the concepts involved a little bit:

First, "^@^D^@^A49" is not a sequence of hexadecimal digits, it is a visualization of keystrokes. ^@ == CTRL+@ for instance.

Hexadecimal numbers are numbers written on the following form:

0xFF00AB12, that is numbers with radix 16. 0 == 0, 1 == 1, ..., 9 == 9, A == 10, B == 11, ..., F == 15. (The 0x is just a standard prefix used to distinguish a hex value from say a binary or decimal number).

If your aim is to initialize a string or integer with full control of where the bits go, I would recommend reading the input from the keyboard as a string of hexadecimal digits (with or without the prefix, your choice.)

Once you have done that, you may use for instance [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) to read the string into an integer.

```
int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);
```

Example:

```
const char * hexstring = "FF800001";
unsigned int value;
sscanf(hexstring, "%x", &value);
```

Comment: If you enter the prefix, you may have to strip it again before passing it to sscanf.

Comment: Actually the sequence has to be parsed from a file not from keyboard so I have no option but to parse and convert ^@^D^@^A into decimal form.

Comment: Then you should instead use binary input. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716250/c-store-read-binary-file-into-buffer/24717935#24717935 as that will take care of the conversion for you.

Comment: @StianV.Svedenborg _'Then you should instead use binary input ...'_ Huh what?

Comment: I'm inferring that he is seeing ^@^D etc because he's trying to open binary file in text mode (in an editor that will show them as such). I can't think of any other reason he would have to see that, unless he's been copying similar output from another source. But I find that less likely.

Comment: Its solved by opening file in binary mode.
Here is the code that worked :)
    const char * fname = "filename";
    char Event_label[2];
    char val[2];
    int value;
    FILE* filp = fopen(fname, "rb" );
    if (!filp) { printf("Error: could not open file %s\n", fname); return -1; }
    char * buffer = new char[BUFFERSIZE];

    fseek(filp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&Event_label, sizeof(char)*4, 1, filp);
    printf("<%-.2s>",Event_label);
    printf("i= %d%d",Event_label[0],Event_label[1]);